# overwriting a property in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there someone out there who can help me with this function. What it suppose to do is set a property in a string and this string is split firstly by a colon (:) for each control and the it checks if there is an id matching and if there is it then checks if there is a property matching if there is a property overwrite the value but my function doesn't seem to overwrite the property it just returns the original string. can someone help

```
var cookieValue = 'id=1&state=normal&theme=purple:id=2&state=maximized&theme=pink:id=3&state=maximized&theme=black';

var setProperties = function (cookie, id, prop, prop_value) {
    var windows = cookie.split(':');            

    var result = $.each(windows, function(index, value) {
        var temp1 = [];
        if(value.indexOf(id) > -1) {
            var temp2 = [];
            var properties = value.split('&');
            var result2 = $.each(properties, function(index, value) {

                if(value.indexOf(prop) > -1) {

                    temp3 = [];
                    temp3 = value.split('=');

                    temp3[1] = prop_value;  

                    temp2.push(temp3.join('='));
                }else {

                    temp2.push(value);
                }

                return temp2.join('&')

            });
            temp1.push(result2.join('&'));
            return temp1

        }
        else{
            temp1.push(value);  
        }
        return temp1;
    })
    return alert(result.join(':'));

}

setProperties(cookieValue, '2', 'theme', 'black');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function setProperties(cookie, id , name, value) {
    var sections = $.map(cookie.split(":"), function (section) {
        var pairs, found = false;

        if (section.indexOf("id=" + id) === 0) {
            pairs = $.map(section.split("&"), function (pair) {
                if (pair.indexOf(name + "=") === 0) {
                    found = true;

                    return name + "=" + value;
                } else {
                    return pair;
                }
            });

            if (!found) {
                pairs.push(name + "=" + value);
            }

            return pairs.join("&");
        } else {
            return section;
        }
    });

    return sections.join(":");
}
```

Comment: You're code works well. I just thought of something what if I dont have that property in string, could you add another condition in you're code to add the property that doesn't exist

Comment: @KDM I updated the function so it adds the property if it's missing. It won't add the `id`, but you can use the same approach to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`Each` doesn't return a value. You had some semicolons missing I edited the code a little. 
It's not production worthy but at least it returns the (partially) correct value.

You will have to figure out how to replace that value in the cookie. I think regex is the best approach or of course you can pass temp1 array between the function but you will have to re-factor your code quite a lot.

```
var cookieValue = 'id=1&state=normal&theme=purple:id=2&state=maximized&theme=pink:id=3&state=maximized&theme=black';

var setProperties = function (cookie, id, prop, prop_value) {
    var windows = cookie.split(':');            

    var result = $.each(windows, function(index, value) {
        var temp1 = [];
        console.log('value' + value);
        console.log('windows'  + windows);
        console.log(cookieValue);
        if(value.indexOf(id) > -1) {
            var temp2 = [];
            var properties = value.split('&');
            var windows = $.each(properties, function(index, value) {

                if(value.indexOf(prop) > -1) {

                    temp3 = [];
                    temp3 = value.split('=');

                    temp3[1] = prop_value;  

                    temp2.push(temp3.join('='));
                }else {

                    temp2.push(value);
                }

                cookieValue  = temp2.join('&');

            });
            temp1.push(temp2.join('&'));
            cookieValue = temp1;

        }
        else{
            temp1.push(value);  
        }
        cookeValue =  temp1;
    })
console.log("new cookie" + cookieValue); // PRINTS new cookieid=2&state=maximized&theme=black

}
setProperties(cookieValue, '2', 'theme', 'black');
```